# как в phalcon получить только данные таблицы

Tags: php, phalcon

> Возвращение результатов моделью¶ В то время как findFirst() возвращает
>   непосредственно экземпляр вызванного класса (когда это возвращаемые
>   данные), метод find() возвращает Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple.
>   Этот объект включает в себя весь функционал такой как, обходы, поиск
>   определенных записей, подсчет и прочее.

Я делаю так

```
 $feedback = FeedBack::find();
 foreach ($feedback as $item) {        
        $temp[] = $item;
    }
$json = json_encode($temp);
```

Если дальше мне нужно использовать как то только этот набор данных 
то  делаю так

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

Иногда просто перечисляю

```
foreach ($feedback as $item) {        
            $temp['id'] = $item->id;
            $temp['name'] = $item->name;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FeedBack::find()->toArray()
```

Comment: Если не затруднит дайте линк где вы это прочли. Вид конечно не ахти, буду искать может object такой же есть

Comment: В смысле, где прочел? В документации по API: https://docs.phalconphp.com/ru/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Resultset_Simple.html